# How can I make my jQuery animations smoother?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I have a page at: http://staging.similarblue.com/portfolio/

For some reason I can't get the animations to run smoothly. YSlow says "The page has a total of 51 HTTP requests and a total weight of 1425.2K bytes with empty cache." My guess is the animations are running slow because of the amount of images on the page (and therefor more images to move on animation). Also possibly because of the background image.

**Would having a lot of images on the page make the animations slow?**

**Does having a large fixed image background make animations slow?**

If you know YSlow and Firebug well, could you take a look and see where I could optimize?

Here's the code to animate the drop-down when you click an image:

```
$('#client-' + currentClient).slideUp('fast',function() {
  slideItDown(id, function() {
    scrollTo(id);
  });
});

function slideItDown(id, callback) {
  $('#client-' + id).slideDown('fast',callback);
}

function scrollTo(id, callback){
  $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#client-thumb-' + id).offset().top + 72
    },'fast','linear',callback);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Post the code you are using to animate.

Comment: The number and size of HTTP requests determines page load time, probably not the speed of the animations. At first glance, your JavaScript (portfolio.js) may be more complicated than necessary. I'm taking a closer look...

Comment: I think @Tokimon nailed it. However, you may not be prepared to sacrifice your background.... It may help some to give #middle a solid background. Also, remove the scroll animation, and run the slideUp and slideDown animations at the same time, and it may help the perceived performance.

Answer (score 0):

After just a bit of fiddled with your page in Chrome. It seems that the `-webkit-background-size: cover;` is your problem. When it is removed your animation runs smoothly.

You could also try using CSS transitions for the animation. Those are hardware (read GPU) accelerated, so the animation will run smoother anyhow.

Comment: Caution - CSS transitions won't work in IE. Of course, neither does background-size: cover ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tokimon. I'm not able to get the same results by removing the `background-size: cover;` and all its relatives. I also can't use CSS transitions because of the lack of support currently. Thanks for poking around. I think it must be due to your initial answer: too many images on the page.

Comment: @Mike I know that transitions is only for webkit (and soon mozilla) but the idea is to use transitions where you can and jquery when you can't :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I see as the main problem. During the animation, the whole page is getting taller. That's making it look a little choppy-- the scroll bar on the right is moving and the page is shifting down. If you can eliminate that it will help. (You can have a white div a the bottom and animate its height down in unison with the div you are opening up. Alternatively, it can open up "on top of" whatever is below it, and not change the height.)

As far as getting the speed up, this I can't tell yet. Speeding them up or slowing them down sometimes helps, as does fading in content after the space is made available. I think getting the height not to change may mostly do it.

I like the overall affect, but the way it appears is a but rough. You can make the whole page appear much smoothly by taking control of the load order of elements as they display. When you pre-load an image (Image.new.src='/img.gif'), it blocks the rest of the JS from running. This might seem bad, but you can force images to load in the proper order-- so you can load your background image before the rest of the page draws, if that's what you'd prefer. Really, you can animate the display of the page with just a little work.

Good luck!